# How to update a modified version of an open-source code?

Tags: php, git, github

I downloaded an open-source PHP code from GitHub, then I made several changes to it locally.

Now the main source code is updated in GitHub.

I want to know what is the easiest way to update my code, and also keep the changes I made. (as these updates will keep happening I want to know a permanent solutions and industry standards for it)

I do not want to make my code public in GitHub.

EDIT: The code was downloaded as zip file, and not as a Git clone.

Comment: How did you download the code from github?

Comment: I downloaded zip file. no git clone unfortunately. but I also would like to know what is the RIGHT way to do it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

If you have **cloned the code from GitHub** to your local machine, then the original repository should still be set up as remote and you should be able to simply `git pull` the changes and merge them into your local code.

[More info on `git pull`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull)

---

If you **downloaded the code as a zip archive** and made your changes to that, it's going to be a lot harder. The easiest way to update your local code then will probably be to merge the changes into your local code base by hand.

Comment: ...and you might want to read about [git merge conflicts](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/) as well. Very likely that there will be conflicts if you change the code locally and then pull new changes from the main repository.

Answer (score 1):

With any luck the library authors allow customisation through public properties or methods, or through class extension, or some other method.

I have a Php library that requires a little personalisation and I can do so through public properties/methods.

This is a very simple example:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    public $bar = 'big';
    public $baz = 'fat';
    public $bat = 'mamma';
}
```

If you wanted the attribute $bat to have a different value you could do this:

```
$foo      = new Foo;
$foo->bat = 'man';
```

Or you could extend the original class:

```
class MyFoo extends Foo
{
    public $bat = 'man';
}

$foo = new MyFoo;
```

Both methods may allow for the original class to be updated without it affecting your code.  Try and avoid editing/forking the original library if at all possible.

If you must edit the library code.  And the library uses Git for version control, you could clone the original code (git clone) and create a new branch for your changes.  And record (commit) and apply (merge) those changes into a refreshed code base as and when necessary.  Git makes this somewhat easier than managing and applying your own changes (diffs/patches) to library code.

If you can identify the version of the Library that you began with (perhaps it was a tagged release) and you can re-obtain the code as it was before, you could compare that to your modified code and create a change set (or sets).  You might be able to git checkout a version of the library as it was before you started, create a new branch (from there), apply your changes, and try and merge back into an updated library.

Comment: Tnx @Progrock, I will get the Git version of the library as it was before and create new branch. Is there an easy way I can compare my modified code to it and create a change-set? Is there a git command for that? I am using Atlassian SourceTree on Mac. And after I get the changes set, I merge them to the latest version, right?

Comment: Simplistically if you do create a branch from a particular snapshot.  Copy your modified files over your checked out branch.  Then do  a `git status`.  Git will give you a summary of changes.  You can then add and commit them (piecemeal if you like).  I'd familiarise yourself with Git, there are some great tutorials available.

Comment: A diff tool, will let you compare files.  Git has its own: `git diff`.